# Dynamic bar charts from json response using morris

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, morris.js

I have a webservice from which I parse data and plot bar charts. I'm using morris.js library.

Problem:
I have a webservice like this:

> http://localhost:9999/hellowebservice/search?select=*

At select query parameter, I pass the values which I want to search like:

> http://localhost:9999/hellowebservice/search?select=x,y

the json response is something like below:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_id" : "abcd",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "x" : [ "10" ],
        "y : [ "20" ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

When I enter `x, y, z` in the select field next time, I want the bar charts to be automatically updated based on the entered fields

NOTE: I'm using `_id` value to be on x-axis and whatever select values entered to be on y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

Initialized morris chart with dummy values.
And then used `morrisChart.setData()` method to dynamically update the chart.